# Android studio showing random code instead original file for flutter project. same file views perfectly in vs-code or notepad

Tags: android, flutter, dart, nul

Here are the screenshots from different IDEs.

Android studio
[image]

VS Code
[image]

Comment: have you installed Dart & Flutter plugin on AS?

Comment: This is a problem of corrupt cache. Go to File from menu and click on invalidate cache/restart and your problem will be fixed

Comment: @Diwyansh yes, I have dart and flutter plugins installed on my android studio and as well as on VScode.

Comment: @ShatanikMahanty I have tried it several times also, I have reinstalled Android studio twice but this problem still exists..:(

Comment: Solved by reinstalling flutter SDK and moving all of my project files to a new location.